# elasticsearch how to group by repetitive items in array without distinct

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the counts group by the repetitive items in array without distinct, use aggs terms but not work

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "keywords": {
       "terms": {
          "field": "keywords"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

documents like:

```
"keywords": [
            "value1",
            "value1",
            "value2"
          ],
```

but the result is:

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": "value1",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "value2",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
]
```

how can i get the result like:

```
"buckets": [
            {
              "key": "value1",
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key": "value2",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
    ]
```

Comment: With your mappings, you cant. Cause your keys are inside the same documents. We could get a count using script, will try to help you tomorrow.

Comment: @LeBigCat Thanks I have learned lucene. I know that Elasticsearch uses lucene and inverted index. The duplicate values have the same key in the inverted table. I’m afraid that the script is too slow. I’m want to modify the mapping like: keywords: [{name: value 1, count: 8},....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I modify the mapping use nested:

```
"keywords": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "count": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
},
```

and query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "keywords": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "keywords"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "keyword_name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "keywords.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sums": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "keywords.count"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
"buckets": [{
    "key": "value1",
    "doc_count": 495,
    "sums": {
        "value": 609
    }
},
{
    "key": "value2",
    "doc_count": 440,
    "sums": {
        "value": 615
    }
},
{
    "key": "value3",
    "doc_count": 319,
    "sums": {
        "value": 421
    }
},
...]
```